# Merging netCDF files with different dimension size into a single file via nco

Tags: netcdf, nco

I have netCDF files, each with different dimensions which I would like to combine in one single file.

The example of two files are

```
netcdf network0005.vm {
dimensions:
    cell\ type\ index = 1 ;
    cell\ type\ index2 = 1 ;
    vertex\ index = 799 ;
    cell\ index = 400 ;
    bond\ index = 2398 ;
variables:
    double Network\:\:time ;
    int Network\:\:numDeadCells ;
    int Network\:\:nClones ;
    double Frame\:\:xWidth ;
    double Frame\:\:yWidth ;
    ... (lines skipped)
```

and

```
netcdf network0004.vm {
dimensions:
    cell\ type\ index = 1 ;
    cell\ type\ index2 = 1 ;
    vertex\ index = 800 ;
    cell\ index = 400 ;
    bond\ index = 2400 ;
variables:
    double Network\:\:time ;
    int Network\:\:numDeadCells ;
    int Network\:\:nClones ;
    double Frame\:\:xWidth ;
    double Frame\:\:yWidth ;
    ... (lines skipped)
```

Each file contains the same dimension and variable names, however, the size of the dimension differs. I have tried combining them with `ncecat -u time network????.vm.nc`, but they show errors because of dimension mismatch.

I would be interested in knowing how to combine/merge them into a single file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to aggregate multiple files together, when those files contain multiples dimensions with differing sizes, is to use "group aggregation" (gag) as described [here](https://nco.sf.net/nco.html#gag). Make sure the output is netCDF4 format, and this should work:

```
ncecat -4 --gag network????.vm.nc out.nc
```

Comment: My netCDF files are in 'classic' format (compatible with scypi.io.netcdf). Is it possible to have output in the classic format as well?

Comment: Unfortunately no, as classic format cannot represent the group hierarchy that group aggregation creates.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `--gag` into your command.